# GCM Push Notifications comes up only for one of the variants

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, android-gradle-plugin

I am developing an APP with 2 variants with following application IDs -

```
com.App.Prod
com.App
```

I have also enabled Google Cloud Messaging for both of the application IDs and I have added the google-services.json to the app folder, which contains both the variants info in it.

But issue is I get push notification only on com.App.Prod but not on com.App. But if i replace the package names even then I get the push notifications only on com.App.Prod but not on the one com.App.

Another issue is when I am expecting a Push notification, it doesnt come up on com.App but when the app is maximized from the running app. Notification's intent is opened which is as expected.

So only issue is I dont see push notifications on com.App. I am not sure what the issue is.

Any ideas or suggestions please.

Comment: can you post you AndroidManifest.xml with the `com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND` receiver?

Comment: And... are you using gradle?